# Can anybody give a pattern on how do i run a cron job on quarterly basis. This job is supposed to run for 14 days on quarterly basis

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, scheduler

I have a job that supposed to run on quarterly basis. But once this job started, it should run for 14 days. Example- job starts on 11th Jan then it should run from 11th jan till 24th jan.Next time it should run on 11th April to 24 April.
Can anyone please suggest cron expression for achieving above requirement?

Comment: Why 11th? Why not 1st? Will it always be 11th-24th?

Comment: It can be 1st that is not the issue.

Comment: So 1st to 14th every quarter is what you want?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Then [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70661085/256196) is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To schedule a cron job to run at midnight on days 1 to 14 of the first month of every quarter:

```
┌───────────── minute: 0
│ ┌───────────── hour: 0
│ │   ┌───────────── day of the month: 1 to 14 inclusive
│ │   │     ┌───────────── months: 1,4,7 and 10
│ │   │     │     ┌───────────── day of the week: all
│ │   │     │     │
┴ ┴ ──┴─ ───┴──── ┴
0 0 1-14 1,4,7,10 * my-script.sh
```

To schedule a task in Spring Boot, which uses an enhanced flavour of cron expressions, add `0` to the front (for *second*) and use `?` (meaning “any”, rather than `*` which means “all”) for the day of week, [specified via the `@Scheduled` annotation](http://schedule-a-task-using-cron-expressions):

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 1-14 1,4,7,10 ?")
```

Comment: Anyone using Spring framework @Scheduled annotation use 0 0 0 1-14 1,4,7,10 ? as cron expression.

Comment: Cool. Your advice has been incorporated into this answer.